# Почему не срабатывает код на scroll?

Tags: javascript

При прокрутке к заголовку "FIRE", ему должен присваиваться класс "_active" . Но это почему то не происходит. Подскажите, что не так :
https://codepen.io/5dc8b3/pen/WNxpjPy?editors=1111

```
const animItems = document.querySelectorAll('._anim-items');
if(animItems.length > 0) {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', animOnScroll);
  function animOnScroll() {
    for(let index = 0; index < animItems.length; index++) {
      const animItem = animItems[index];
      const animItemHeight = animItem.offsetHeight;
      const animItemOffset = offset(animItem).top;
      console.log(animItemOffset)
      const animStart = 4;
     

      let animItemPoint = window.innerHeight - animItemHeight / animStart;

      if (animItemHeight > window.innerHeight) {
        animItemPoint = window.innerHeight - window.innerHeight / animStart;
      }

      if ((pageYOffset > animItemOffset - animItemPoint) &&  pageYOffset < (animItemOffset + animItemHeight)) {
        console.log('bibobe')
        animItem.classList.add('_active');
      } else {
        animItem.classList.remove('_active');
      }
    }
  }
  function offset(el) {
    const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect(),
      scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft,
      scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    return { top: rect.top + scrollTop, left: rect.left + scrollLeft }
  }
  animOnScroll();
}
```

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что это не происходит? По ссылке все корректно работает

Answer (score -1):

Посмотрите на кусочек [отсюда](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event)
Думаю, что у вас может не работать из-за пропусков события указанный в ссылке.

> Пропуск тактов события прокрутки
>
> Поскольку события прокрутки могут запускаться с высокой скоростью,
> обработчик событий не должен выполнять вычислительно-емкие операции,
> такие как модификации DOM.

Comment: Может поясните минус? какие ожидания или что ещё

Comment: Как данная цитата относится к вопросу?

Comment: @Grundy к тому что почему это может неверно работать. Как вы указали это работает. Я указал почему может нет

Comment: В цитате не указано почему это может не работать.

Comment: @Grundy, добавил возможную причину

Comment: это не может быть причиной

Comment: @Grundy да без проблем возможно так и есть. Аргументировать можно, а не просто "не может".

Comment: Ты неправильно понял, о чем написано по ссылке. Там наоборот указано, что пользователь **должен** делать throttle для частых событий, а не что эти события куда-то пропадают

Comment: в данном коде каждое событие обрабатывается, следовательно ничего не теряется.

Comment: @Grundy То что не теряется это твое утверждение. А вот автор задаёт другой вопрос. Мой ответ лишь показывает что возможно не вызывается последний необходимый скролл который должен сменить класс.

Comment: Он не может не вызываться :) я ж говорю - ты неправильно понял о чем написано в твоей ссылке. Попробуй прочитать английский вариант, возможно он будет понятнее.